# How to only allow user to rotate a game object clockwise?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a game object which can be rotated by the user:

```
public class RotatableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void RotateAccordingTo(Hand hand)
    {
        Quaternion desiredRotation = hand.CurrentRotation;
        desiredRotation.y = 0;
        desiredRotation.z = 0;

        this.transform.localRotation = desiredRotation;  
    }
}
```

Right now, the user is able to rotate it both counter-clockwise and clockwise.

I wish to modify the code so that the object does not rotate when the user tries to turn it counter-clockwise. It rotates only if the user is turning it clockwise.

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: Mmmm, maybe you could make a quaternion delta, of the last rotation and the actual rotation, and there you could determine if the rotation's velocity points clockwise.

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter Thank you for your comment. Will you kindly use code to explain what you mean? Sorry for the stupid question.